# How to make one Shared Thread over all Activity?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

This is about **android programming Concept**

I wonder what would happened ?
If let say I have **one Android Project.**

IT has two activities.

**Activity - A:** 
Containing a Thread of Socket to the Server.

**Activity - B:**
No Socket at all. Just the UI rendering.

**How to ensure that this Thread in Activity-A,
always running whenever I go to any activities i
have in this project?**

What is your best design concept?

1. Passing a Thread over every Constructor / Intent of the next
   Activity Called?
2. Create a Static Thread that could be shared in anywhere (Any
   Activity access)
3. or somethingelse?

*NB: We dont want the thread re-created over and over again. And also we dont want it to be destroyed. Unless, we quit our app.*

Comment: *Activity - A: Containing a Thread of Socket to the Server.* - Use a `service/ Asynctask`. Don't use `Activity` if there is no UI.

Comment: "Unless, we quit our app" - that's not as easy as it sounds in android ... Do you just Exit the Activity (with Home or Back Buttons) or do you have an explicit "Exit App"-Button in the App?

Comment: Checkout the services concept in Android

Comment: you can not prevent the `Thread` from being destroyed by the runtime

Comment: @suitianshi, "can't prevent Thread being destroyed"? is that mean If I created an object of Thread in Activity A, and then i move to Activity B, means the Thread within Activity A is destroyed?

IspasClaudiu, thanks I will....

Fildor, No, there's no Exit app button. I even don't know how to exit from one activity that could close every activities I just opened lately. I thought there's System.exit(0) as java does, but android doesn't. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a "Service" instead of "Activty A".

You can read about Services here: [Android Developer Site](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

You might also want to pay attention to the Activities' LifeCycle. [Again - Developer Site](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle)
You'll see that in Android you do not have a perfect match for a PC's "Exit the App".

First of all: Your Activity may be closed anytime if the OS needs Memory. What do want to do in this case?
Also keep in mind, that a "always running" Service is bad for battery lifetime. So you should carefully plan the runtime (in the sense of "time it is actually running") of a service and keep it low.
If it is appropriate, you might be better off using a connectionless approach (UDP) to avoid keeping up a steady TCP-Connection. Of course that's out of question if the requirement is to use TCP.

If you only want to decouple a lenghty download, using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) may be sufficient.

ADDENDUM:

**I know I should not provide links, only.** But the reader may agree that developer.android.com is pretty likely to be a pretty stable source and the content much to broad to repeat it on here.

Comment: i see then.
So for my case here, it's better to put every Thread Socket creation within a Service, right? Because I need some communication between the service towards every Activities then i shall use IntentService, right @Fildor?

Comment: Well, an IntentService is good for decoupling lengthy operations and Network communication in particular, yes. If that fits in your requirements, I recommend using one. But read the Docu carefully. I cannot possibly explain every pit there is using a Service, here. But the delveloper site is really a very good source to get along.

Comment: could you explain more @Fildor, what if I have a Thread inside that Service, and multiple activities are binding into it. Is it the Thread inside that service is recreated as one Activity moves to another activities as well?